# How test functions imported in component from outside?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I write test for component which use FileSaver in it method. 
I don't know how covered usage FileSaver by unit tests in Angular7

Code example:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
 someMethod() {
   FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob());
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
const spyFileSaver = spyOn(FileSaver,'saveAs');
spyFileSave.toHaveBeenCalled();
```